# youtube iframe player - javascript to change playlist

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

does anyone know how and what javascript to use to change the playlist of a iframe youtube player?

I have searched the net but can't seem to find a simple piece of code for it.

Comment: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=238955

Comment: please post your code as part of the question and not as a link in the comments. one click is the difference between good and bad UX you know :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [loadPlaylist()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadPlaylistObj) function of the YouTube Player API.

Comment: Solved this by using:

onclick="return changeIframeSrc('video_player', this.href)"

Thanks for answering @Jeff Posnick :)